# Stay on page 3 minutes using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is it possible to request a page with AJAX and stay on that page for about 3 minutes before the ajax function returns, to wait some dynamic content to load up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible if you notify user if user tries to close page before your ajax completes:

```
var ajaxCompleted = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (!ajaxCompleted) {
        return 'This page is still loading, please don\'t close it!';
    }
};

makeAjaxCall(function() {
    ajaxCompleted = true;
});
```

Comment: keep in mind not all browsers will present the message though. Some like Firefox will only display default message